# Why the infinite coin toss and then $\lambda$ on $\mathfrak{B}((0,1])$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I realize this is an odd sort of a question but I'm trying to see how all the bits fit together and I'm having difficulty seeing where these two pieces fit.

I'm working my way through a set of online lectures (several years old) on probability theory for graduate engineers. The lecturer finished the discussion of discrete sample spaces and then went on to the infinite coin toss sample space. Then he moved to a different (related) continuous sample space, the unit interval. He devoted one lecture to a Lebesgue measure on $\mathfrak{B}((0,1])$ via Caratheodory's extension theorem. At the end he explained that $\lambda$ cannot be a probability measure on $\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$ because it blows up.

Next he took up random variables and we quickly find that these nifty little functions can induce a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. That got me to wondering.

Why the coin toss model and why the $\lambda$ on the unit interval? We had the discrete sample space and with random variables we get a probability space on the continuum. What do these other two pieces do, apart from than being very interesting, especially that remarkable theorem.

Put another way, if you wanted a lean approach to probability on discrete and continuous spaces, would the coin toss and Lebesgue on the unit interval be necessary or even useful?

Comment: If I were doing only probability theory, I'd certainly discuss the coin toss model, as it's needed for lots of theorems (like the simplest version of the strong law of large numbers). A careful treatment of this will need Caratheodory's extension theorem. 
I'd probably also mention that this probability space is isomorphic to the unit interval with Lebesgue measure (up to countably many points, which don't affect the measure).

Comment: @AndreasBlass; Thank you, that's good to know. I didn't/don't get the connection between the coin toss and the LLN (or the ``lots of theorems'').  If you have a link that would be great (as junior as possible -- it should be clear I'm a complete novice). I do get  its relationship to [0,,1], hence the (related) aside but your succinct description is far better than I would have come up with.  // The deeper I go the deeper it gets!

Comment: The strong law of large numbers is about the almost-sure behavior of a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. The simplest special case is where those variables are fair coin flips. Then the probability space on which the sequence is defined is the coin-toss space $\{0,1\}^{"\mathbb N}$.